# Editing JSON format after $.get function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I need to change the format for my JSON data that is received from the server, I'm struggling to understand the JSON properties and looks very daunting. Any advice/solution would be appreciated.

Here is what the data looks like upon receiving.

```
[
  {
    "date": "2006-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "date_processed": "2006-06-30T17:45:25.217Z",
    "amount": 98,
    "payment_type": "Debit Order",
    "status": "Collected"
  },
  {
    "date": "2006-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "date_processed": "2006-07-28T17:20:54.000Z",
    "amount": 98,
    "payment_type": "Debit Order",
    "status": "Collected"
  }
]
```

I need this to look like:

```
 "page":1,
 "total":2,
 "rows":[
  {
    "cell": {
     "date": "2006-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
     "date_processed": "2006-06-30T17:45:25.217Z",
     "amount": 98,
     "payment_type": "Debit Order",
     "status": "Collected"
     }
  },
  {
    "cell": {
     "date": "2006-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
     "date_processed": "2006-06-30T17:45:25.217Z",
     "amount": 98,
     "payment_type": "Debit Order",
     "status": "Collected"
     }
  }
  ]
```

Comment: How is page and total to be calculated?

Comment: @TAS thats for flexigrid :)

Comment: If you are the one that generates this on the serverside, that would be the right place to change it, and not on the clientside.

Comment: @SnakeEater Should they always be 1 and 2?

Comment: @adeneo we want to keep all json data in a generic form thats why I want to do it on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var targetObject = {page: 1, total: 2, rows: []}
    yourJSON.each(function (item) {
       targetObject.rows.push({cell: item});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
 var oldJSON = [{}], //your JSON from the server

 newJSON = {
     "page":1,
     "total":oldJSON.length,
     "rows":[]
 };

 for (var i = 0, dataLen = newJSON.total; i < dataLen; i = i + 1) {
      newJSON.rows[i].cell = oldJSON[i]
 }
```